# MongoDB - Array element as variable

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query

Lets say here is the same document:

```
{
"_id" : 1.0,
"custname" : "metlife",
"address" : {
    "city" : "Bangalore",
    "country" : "INDIA"
 }
}
```

And if I want to push an extra field to this document, something like below:

```
db.customers.updateMany(
  {"address.country":"INDIA"},
  {$push : {city: "$address.country"}}

)
```

It results in wrong update:

```
{
"_id" : 1.0,
"custname" : "metlife",
"address" : {
    "city" : "Bangalore",
    "country" : "INDIA"
 },
 "city" : "$address.city"
}
```

Instead of this:

```
{
"_id" : 1.0,
"custname" : "metlife",
"address" : {
    "city" : "Bangalore",
    "country" : "INDIA"
 },
 "city" : "Bangalore"
}
```

How do I achieve the above result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't refer to other field values in update currently (more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field)). There is a workaround in aggregation framework (using [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html)) but it will replace entire collection.

I think that you can consider using [$rename](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/) in your case. It will not add new field but it can move `city` to the top level of your document.

```
db.customers.updateMany({"address.country":"INDIA"}, {$rename: {"address.city": "city"}})
```

will give you following structure:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "custname" : "metlife", "address" : { "country" : "INDIA" }, "city" : "Bangalore" }
```

Comment: Thanks for the note :)

Comment: Can you tell me what are those `false` and `true` stands for? 
Does it represent `upsert/multi` ?

Comment: @RahulRaj sorry, I tested this case on update operation, you don't need them for `updateMany`

Answer (score 0):

like @mickl said : You can't refer to other field values in update currently,
you have to iterate through your collection to update the documents, try this :

```
db.eval(function() { 
    db.collection.find({"address.country":"INDIA"}).forEach(function(e) {
        e.city= e.address.city;
        db.collection.save(e);
    });
});
```

Keep in mind that this will block the DB until all updates are done.

Comment: You meant to say DB will be locked until this execution is completed?

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
db.customers.updateMany(
  {"address.country":"INDIA"},
  {$push : {city: "address.country"}}

)
```

remove $ sign